# PORQUE NO INSERTA DATOS EN LA TABLA

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema cuando quiero insertar datos a mi tabla usuarios, no los inserta y me manda lo que puse en el `OR DIE` (NO INSERTO DATOS). Pero no se porque.

Esta es mi tabla y códigos:

[image: tabla usuarios]

Se que es mucho código, pero quise ponerlo todo por si acaso, pero el problema creo que esta en lo primero de PHP

```
<?php
include('php_conexion.php'); 

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pure CSS3 Menu</title>
        <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="prefix-free.js"></script>


    </head>

<body>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ingresar']))
    #if(!empty($_POST['nomDistrOrigen']) and !empty($_POST['nomUsuario']) and !empty($_POST['nickUsuario']) and !empty($_POST['nomTipo']))
    {


        {
            $nomUsuario=$_POST['nomUsuario'];   
            $apeUsuario = $_POST['apeUsuario']; 
            #$nomTipo= $_POST['nomTipo']; 
            $nickUsuario=$_POST['nickUsuario'];
            $passUsuario= $_POST['pass']; $fechaInicio=date("Y-m-j"); $emailUsuario=$_POST['emailUsuario']; $telUsuario= $_POST['telUsuario']; $direcUsuario=$_POST['direcUsuario'];
            $cpUsuario= $_POST['cpUsuario']; $descUsuario= $_POST['descUsuario']; 
            $cuentaB= $_POST['cuentaB'];
            $nomDistrOrigen= $_POST['nomDistrOrigen']; $estadoDistr= $_POST['estadoDistr']; 
            $munDistr= $_POST['munDistr']; $direcDistr= $_POST['direcDistr']; $cpDistr= $_POST['cpDistr']; 


            $query="insert into usuarios( nomUsuario, apeUsuario, nickUsuario, pass, emailUsuario, telUsuario, direcUsuario, cpUsuario, descUsuario, cuentaB, nomDistrOrigen, estadoDistr, munDistr, direcDistr, cpDistr) VALUES('$nomUsuario', '$apeUsuario', '$nickUsuario', '$passUsuario', '$emailUsuario', '$telUsuario', '$direcUsuario', '$cpUsuario', '$descUsuario', '$cuentaB', '$nomDistrOrigen', '$estadoDistr', '$munDistr', '$direcUsuario', '$cpDistr')";

            #mysqli_query($conexion ,$query);
            $resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("error al insertar datos");

            echo "<p style='color:green;'>INSERCION REALIZADA CON EXITO</p>";
        }
    }


?>


    <right><p> cerrar sesion</p></right>
<div class="wrap">
  <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index_admin2.php"><span class="iconic home"></span> Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic plus-alt"></span> Ventas</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Buscar Ventas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">En Proceso</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lista</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic chat"></span> Distribuidores</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Nuevo Distribuidor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Buscar Distribuidor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lista</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic check"></span> Productos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="producto_nuevo.php">Nuevo Producto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Luces</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Valeros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">etc...</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic key"></span> Marcas</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MonkeyLight</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bkool</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Motorex</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic chat-alt"></span> Usuarios</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="usuario_nuevo.php">Nuevo Usuario</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Modificar Usuarior</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic book"></span> Datos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="crear_usuarios.php">Datos Personales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Configuracion</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </nav>
    </div>
     <figure>
  <center><input name="search" type="search" id="search" size="60">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Buscar"></center>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
    <CENTER>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <h1><strong>NUEVO USUARIO</strong></h1>

<form name="formulario" method="post" action="">                
<table width="990" border="1">
      <caption>&nbsp;
    </caption>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="400">Nombre </td>
          <td width="400">Direccion del Usuario</td>
          <td width="400">Nombre de la Empresa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><p>
            <input placeholder="Nombre" type="text" name="nomUsuario" id="nomUsuario">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Apellidos</p>
          <p>
            <input placeholder="Apellidos" type="text" name="apeUsuario" id="apeUsuuario">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Tipo Usuario</p>
          <p>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="nomTipo" value="Administrador" id="nomTipo">
              Administrador </label>
            <br>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="nomTipo" value="Distribuidor" id="Marca_1">
              Distribuidor</label>
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Nick</p>
          <p>
            <input placeholder="Nick" type="text" name="nickUsuario" id="textfield4">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Contraseña</p>
          <p>
            <input placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" name="pass" id="textfield50">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Repetir Contraseña</p>
          <p>
            <input placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" type="password" name="pass2" id="textfield10">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>E-mail</p>
          <p>
            <input placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="emailUsuario" id="textfield20">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Teléfono/Celular</p>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="telUsuario" id="textfield14">
          </p></td>
          <td><p>
            <input name="direcUsuario" type="text" id="textfield" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Codigo Postal </p>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="cpUsuario" id="textfield6">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Porcentaje Descuento</p>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="descUsuario" id="textfield7">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Cuenta de Banco
            <input name="cuentaB" type="text" id="textfield2" size="40">
        </p>
          </td>
          <td><p>
            <input name="nomDistrOrigen" type="text" id="textfield11" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Estado</p>
          <p>
            <input name="estadoDistr" type="text" id="textfield12" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Municipio          </p>
          <p>
            <input name="munDistr" type="text" id="textfield15" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Codigo Postal </p>
          <p>
            <input name="cpDistr" type="text" id="textfield16" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp; </p>
          <p>Direccion</p>
          <p>
            <input name="direcDistr" type="text" id="textfield17" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>
            <input name="ingresar"  type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="INGRESAR">
            <input name="cancelar"  type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="CANCELAR">
          </p></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
        </form>
</center>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: por que dentro de las llaves del if, vuelves a abrir otras llaves?, quita esas llaves innecesarias son del if que tienes comentado

Comment: Hay un fallo en la tercera linea Primer caracter de tu php: #$nomTipo= $_POST['nomTipo'];

Comment: Debes normalizar esa tabla y definir bien los nombres de cada campo, no entiendo como no te pierdes.

Comment: las llaves eran porque tenia otro if..
el "            #$nomTipo= $_POST['nomTipo']; " es porque lo tengo en comentarios por esp no afecta. PERO AUN NO ENTIENDO QUE NO INGRESE DATOS, O LOS NOMBRES DE LOS CAMPOS INFLUYE,

Answer (score 1):

LA SOLUCION FUE SENCILLA, me siento algo menso por no verlo antes
LE AGREGUE 
.mysqli_error($conexion)
A MI LINEA DE ERROR Y ME DIJO DESPUES DE METER DATOS QUE CIERTOS CAMPOS DE MI TABLA NO ESTABAN -NULL- 
ES DECIR, PARA QUE FUNCIONARA EL CODIGO SIMPLEMENTE A MIS CAMPOS DE MYSQL LOS HICE PREDETERMINADOS NULL

Comment: Gracias por colocar la respuesta  y ayudar a crecer la comunidad

Answer (score -1):

Y ahora me doy cuenta de que tienes mal hecha la inserción de datos en la query
'Acabo de Darme cuenta de que no tienes la variable $Conexión definida con su 'función asociada de conexion, revisa este código...

```html
<?php
    

include('php_conexion.php'); 
    
    ?>
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
    
    
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Pure CSS3 Menu</title>
            <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="iconic.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="prefix-free.js"></script>
    
    
        </head>
    
    <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['ingresar']))
        #if(!empty($_POST['nomDistrOrigen']) and !empty($_POST['nomUsuario']) and !empty($_POST['nickUsuario']) and !empty($_POST['nomTipo']))
        {
    
    
            {
                $nomUsuario=$_POST['nomUsuario'];   
                $apeUsuario = $_POST['apeUsuario'];
                // Aqui estaba el error
                $nomTipo= $_POST['nomTipo']; 
                $nickUsuario=$_POST['nickUsuario'];
                $passUsuario= $_POST['pass']; $fechaInicio=date("Y-m-j"); $emailUsuario=$_POST['emailUsuario']; $telUsuario= $_POST['telUsuario']; $direcUsuario=$_POST['direcUsuario'];
                $cpUsuario= $_POST['cpUsuario']; $descUsuario= $_POST['descUsuario']; 
                $cuentaB= $_POST['cuentaB'];
                $nomDistrOrigen= $_POST['nomDistrOrigen']; $estadoDistr= $_POST['estadoDistr']; 
                $munDistr= $_POST['munDistr']; $direcDistr= $_POST['direcDistr']; $cpDistr= $_POST['cpDistr']; 
    $conexion = @mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "" , "bd");
                $query="insert into usuarios( 'nomUsuario', 'apeUsuario', 'nickUsuario', 'pass', 'emailUsuario', 'telUsuario', 'direcUsuario', 'cpUsuario', 'descUsuario', 'cuentaB', 'nomDistrOrigen', 'estadoDistr', 'munDistr', 'direcDistr', 'cpDistr') VALUES($nomUsuario, $apeUsuario, $nickUsuario, $passUsuario, $emailUsuario, $telUsuario, $direcUsuario, $cpUsuario, $descUsuario, $cuentaB, $nomDistrOrigen, $estadoDistr, $munDistr, $direcUsuario, $cpDistr)";
    
                @mysqli_query($conexion ,$query);
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("error al insertar datos");
    
                echo "<p style='color:green;'>INSERCION REALIZADA CON EXITO</p>";
            }
        }
    
    
    ?>
    
    
        <right><p> cerrar sesion</p></right>
    <div class="wrap">
      <nav>
          <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index_admin2.php"><span class="iconic home"></span> Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic plus-alt"></span> Ventas</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Buscar Ventas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">En Proceso</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lista</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic chat"></span> Distribuidores</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Nuevo Distribuidor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Buscar Distribuidor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lista</a></li>
    
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic check"></span> Productos</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="producto_nuevo.php">Nuevo Producto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Luces</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Valeros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">etc...</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    
                <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic key"></span> Marcas</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">MonkeyLight</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bkool</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Motorex</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic chat-alt"></span> Usuarios</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="usuario_nuevo.php">Nuevo Usuario</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Modificar Usuarior</a></li>
    
                    </ul>
                </li>
    
                <li><a href="#"><span class="iconic book"></span> Datos</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="crear_usuarios.php">Datos Personales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Configuracion</a></li>
    
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </nav>
        </div>
         <figure>
      <center><input name="search" type="search" id="search" size="60">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Buscar"></center>
      <figcaption></figcaption>
    </figure>
        <CENTER>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1><strong>NUEVO USUARIO</strong></h1>
    <!-- aquí el action="" no puede estar en blanco sino donde hace submit -->
    <form name="formulario" method="post" action="">                
    <table width="990" border="1">
          <caption>&nbsp;
        </caption>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="400">Nombre </td>
              <td width="400">Direccion del Usuario</td>
              <td width="400">Nombre de la Empresa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>
                <input placeholder="Nombre" type="text" name="nomUsuario" id="nomUsuario">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Apellidos</p>
              <p>
                <input placeholder="Apellidos" type="text" name="apeUsuario" id="apeUsuuario">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Tipo Usuario</p>
              <p>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="nomTipo" value="Administrador" id="nomTipo">
                  Administrador </label>
                <br>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="nomTipo" value="Distribuidor" id="Marca_1">
                  Distribuidor</label>
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Nick</p>
              <p>
                <input placeholder="Nick" type="text" name="nickUsuario" id="textfield4">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Contraseña</p>
              <p>
                <input placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" name="pass" id="textfield50">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Repetir Contraseña</p>
              <p>
                <input placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" type="password" name="pass2" id="textfield10">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>E-mail</p>
              <p>
                <input placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="emailUsuario" id="textfield20">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Teléfono/Celular</p>
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="telUsuario" id="textfield14">
              </p></td>
              <td><p>
                <input name="direcUsuario" type="text" id="textfield" size="40">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Codigo Postal </p>
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="cpUsuario" id="textfield6">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Porcentaje Descuento</p>
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="descUsuario" id="textfield7">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Cuenta de Banco
                <input name="cuentaB" type="text" id="textfield2" size="40">
            </p>
              </td>
              <td><p>
                <input name="nomDistrOrigen" type="text" id="textfield11" size="40">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Estado</p>
              <p>
                <input name="estadoDistr" type="text" id="textfield12" size="40">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Municipio          </p>
              <p>
                <input name="munDistr" type="text" id="textfield15" size="40">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>Codigo Postal </p>
              <p>
                <input name="cpDistr" type="text" id="textfield16" size="40">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp; </p>
              <p>Direccion</p>
              <p>
                <input name="direcDistr" type="text" id="textfield17" size="40">
              </p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>
                <input name="ingresar"  type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="INGRESAR">
                <input name="cancelar"  type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="CANCELAR">
              </p></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
            </form>
    </center>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Y esto soluciona el problema (que no sabemos cual es) por qué???? Explicar las respuestas es muy importante. y no duplicar las respuestas tambien.

Comment: gracias por guiarme. ya elimine la linea de codigo de error que me dices (aunque segun yo poner primero el '#' hace comentario y no debe de afectar nada) y tambien en modifique action asi   action="usuario_nuevo.php" y al ingresar datos en la pagina me manda al error de 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("error al insertar datos");
gracias por tu apoyo, y en verdad necesito ayuda y no se que hacer ya

Comment: aun no funciona. esa variable estaba en conexion.php
la volvi a poner donde me dices, y no funciona. me sigue mandando al error de ingreso

Comment: hola. quise ingresar un solo dato, el nombre y tambien me sale error